# Why redis does not use Direct IO?

Tags: caching, redis, buffer

As redis is a large buffer, there is no need for kernel to cache the buffer for redis.

**Why doesn't it use Direct IO?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct I/O would be a poor choice for the following reasons:

- For AOF, we need to decorrelate the write operation from the fsync operation since they may not happen in the same thread. You cannot do that when you use direct IO.
- For AOF rewrite and RDB, stdio (buffered IO) is used, since a lot of small objects are written. I don't think you can use O_DIRECT together with stdio (there are constraints attached to O_DIRECT ...). To use direct IO, we would have to write our own buffering system on top of the low level API.
- O_DIRECT is not available with all filesystems, and it is not portable.
- Sometimes the buffer cache is actually useful. For instance when a slave connects to a master, it will request a RDB dump, and then read this dump. Without buffer cache, this operation would generate twice the I/O.
- Generally, the dump file is much smaller than the data in memory. In many cases, you would not gain as much as you think.

While O_DIRECT is probably not a good solution for Redis, using posix_fadvise with POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED option could be useful in some cases. In the past, I played with a simple implementation of this for the RDB dump.